# Crashlytics - codesign user interaction is not allowed

Tags: ios, jenkins, codesign, crashlytics

I've been building an iOS app on our Jenkins server with no problems until I've added the Crashlytics framework to that project.

Now it fails when running this command:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 97B4681D342EA8BD5AE8D283B6A924BF6AF3CF95 --resource-rules=/Users/jenkins/dev/workspace/megared-ios/build/Megared\ Stage.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Megared-hitcnfjdmnrzijfoehutangiwnos/Build/Intermediates/Megared.build/Stage-iphoneos/Megared.build/Megared\ Stage.xcent /Users/jenkins/dev/workspace/megared-ios/build/Megared\ Stage.app
```

The error is the following:

```
/Users/jenkins/dev/workspace/megared-ios/build/Megared Stage.app: User interaction is not allowed.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have a shell script that runs at the beginning of the build project that creates a new keychain, imports the certificates for distribution, copies the mobileprovision to the correct Library folder and unlocks the newly created keychain.

If I remove the Crashlytis script from the build phases, it goes back to building fine.

It looks like something happens when the "run" command of Crashlytics is being called, just like if the keychain gets locked up again or just messed up. I'm struggling to find a solution.

**Update:**

It looks like the failing command from Crashlytics is this one and it's got nothing to do with the GUI:

```
2014-04-28 09:40:45.004 run[54378:507] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.6
2014-04-28 09:40:45.033 run[54378:507] 

Crashlytics: Src root /Users/jenkins/dev/workspace/megared-ios/Megared
2014-04-28 09:40:45.033 run[54378:507] 

Crashlytics: Current directory path /Users/jenkins/dev/workspace/megared-ios/Megared
2014-04-28 09:40:45.035 run[54378:507] 

Crashlytics: Run script build phase called from Xcode Bots 0
2014-04-28 09:40:45.036 run[54378:507] 

Crashlytics: Run script build phase called from Xcode.app 0
2014-04-28 09:40:46.612 run[54378:507] 

Crashlytics: Could not be onboarded statusCode 404
2014-04-28 09:40:49.805 run[54378:507] 

Crashlytics: Uploading dSYM at path /Users/jenkins/dev/workspace/megared-ios/build/Megared Stage.app.dSYM
2014-04-28 09:41:39.635 run[54378:507] 

Crashlytics: Uploading dSYM at path /Users/jenkins/dev/workspace/megared-ios/build/Megared Stage.app.dSYM
2014-04-28 09:42:02.295 run[54378:507] 

Crashlytics: Megared Stage.app.dSYM could not be uploaded statusCode 0 Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x10026a490 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1002add30 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.crashlytics.com/api/v1/1fc7b0115d986225bd4df420f1a979cd6114256d/dsyms, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.crashlytics.com/api/v1/1fc7b0115d986225bd4df420f1a979cd6114256d/dsyms, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hey, have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: It solved by itself after a few new versions of Crashlytics. Once it got out of beta it started working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds you need to run Jenkins in a GUI session. You seem to have installed Jenkins to run as a background daemon where it has no access to GUI to draw windows or access any of the services a GUI application needs. I made https://github.com/stisti/jenkins-app for this purpose. Or you can just run "java -jar jenkins.war" in a Terminal window.